# Issue with the XML while creating Channel

Tags: xml, cics

This is my first XML code, I'm trying to create Channel Description document. Please find the XML and error below.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
<copyright 
 notice="cics-lm-source-program" 
 pids="5655-Y04" 
 years="2009" 
 crc="2720895662" > 
  
                      
 Licensed Materials - Property of IBM 
  
 5655-Y04 
  
 (C) Copyright IBM Corp. 2009 All Rights Reserved. 
  
 US Government Users Restricted Rights - Use, duplication or 
 disclosure restricted by GSA ADP Schedule Contract with 
 IBM Corp. 
  
 @{[**]copyright.years=2009} 
  
              
 </copyright> 
-->
<element name="schema">
  <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/CICS/channel"
    xmlns:tns="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/CICS/channel"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <element name="channel">
        <channel name="PMTRECONCHN" xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/CICS/channel">     
          <complexType>
            <sequence>
                <element name="container" maxOccurs="unbounded"
                    minOccurs="0">
                    <container name="PMTRECON" type="bit" use="required">
                      <complexType>
                        <sequence>
                            <element name="structure" minOccurs="0">
                                <structure location="//A.P1.CM.ZZ.STAGE.CALU.#000404.CPY(PMTRECON)"/>
                                <complexType>
                                    <attribute name="location" type="string" use="required"/>
                                    <attribute name="structure" type="string" use="optional"/>
                            </complexType>
                            </element>
                        </sequence>
                        <attribute name="name" type="tns:name16Type" use="required"/>
                        <attribute name="type" type="tns:typeType" use="required"/>
                        <attribute name="use"  type="tns:useType" use="required"/>
                      </complexType>
                    </container>
                </element>
            </sequence>
            <attribute name="name" type="tns:name16Type" use="optional" />
          </complexType>
        </channel> 
    </element>
    
    <simpleType name="name16Type">
        <restriction base="string">
            <maxLength value="16"/>
        </restriction>
    </simpleType>
    
    <simpleType name="typeType">
        <restriction base="string">
            <enumeration value="char"/>
            <enumeration value="bit"/>
        </restriction>
    </simpleType>
    
    <simpleType name="useType">
        <restriction base="string">
            <enumeration value="required"/>
            <enumeration value="optional"/>
        </restriction>
    </simpleType>    

  </schema>
</element>
```

Error: DFHPI9027E The XML parser has found error. "cvc.elt1: Cannot find declaration of element 'element.' at line 25 and cloumn 24 in document.

Please help me to fix this. I don't know anything about XML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XML you have posted is an XML schema document.  That's not what you use as a channel description document.  You will create a **normal** XML document that conforms to the schema shown on this page: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGMCP_5.4.0/applications/developing/web-services/dfhws_channeldesc_json.html

Here's a sample channel description document:

```
<channel name=”fund” xmlns=http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/CICS/channel>
    <container name=”fundAdmin” type=”char” use=”required”>
          <structure location=”//WSPOT01.CICSLAB.UTIL(FUNDADMN)”/>
    </container>
    <container name=”fundHistory” type=”char” use=”optional”>
          <structure location=”//WSPOT01.CICSLAB.UTIL(FUNDHSRY)”/>
    </container>
</channel>
```